# "Applying Directory Permissions to Files in Linux: Ownership and Access Query"

Tags: permissions, filesystems

I am currently learning about Linux file permissions and have a query related to permissions on directories and files.

Suppose there is a file `x` owned by a user `user1` and belonging to a specific group. If I am not the owner of the file but I own the directory containing the file and have certain permissions, can I apply the directory permissions to the file, even though I am not the owner of the file but only the owner of the directory?

Comment: Why not just test it out?

Comment: Looks like a homework question.